Prove that Inefficient PRGs exist unconditionally
Im trying to prove that an inefficient double-lengthening PRG exists.
My current approach is to produce a single random bit $b$ and output $r,b$. After producing the 'random' bit a length extension technique can be applied.
A candidate for such a random bit is $<r,x_r>$ where $<\cdot,\cdot>$ is inner product mod $n$.
Another direction is returning $r,f(r)$
Unfortunately, I am not able to proceed with the proof - will appreciate any hints\directions.
Thanks!
**This was already in Inefficient double-lengthening PRG but no answer was provided

What is $f$? There can't be information theoretic PRGs because an n-bit seed can only have at most n bits of entropy - and a PRG needs longer outputs. But if inefficient means taking time longer than the adversary, you can use a complexity theoretic PRG, e.g. the Nisan-Wigderson PRG https://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/NOAM/HARDNESS/final.pdf. The minimum assumption there is that there exists a hard problem for the adversary, i.e. a problem that is assumed to take more time to solve than the adversary's runtime.
